# $function() and $$variable

Tags: php

What the heck is `$function();` and `$$variable` for?

Have never heard of these before, and searching on google doesn't give anything useful (possible that my keywords aren't perfect).

via https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4891301/top-bad-practices-in-php/4891422#4891422

Answer (score 13, accepted):

`$function()` is a [variable function](http://php.net/functions.variable-functions) and `$$variable` is a [variable variable](http://php.net/variables.variable).

Those linked pages should give you plenty to go on, or at the very least some actual words to search with.

Answer (score 5):

`$$variable` <strike>can be quite useful. What it</strike> does:

```
$a = 1;
$b = "a";
echo $$b;
```

Outputs `1`

Comment: I've never seen a use for `$$` that wasn't an outright abuse.  Variable functions, ok.  But straight variable variables (with double `$$`), never.  Please prove me wrong with how *useful* they can be in good code...

Comment: @ircmaxell I wanted to add an example, but I can´t seem to think of any :-) Where I have used a similar construction was when generating a new object where the type / class depended on a variable (all sub-classes of a main class), something like `$product = new $type($some_var)` where `$type` is the kind of product I wanted to create. I guess that´s similar.

Comment: It's similar and acceptable to do that.  But I've just never see `$$` where it's not an example of what to do.  I'd love to be proven wrong, but we'll see...

Comment: @ircmaxell You are probably right, it seems the only time they come up is when people want to know what they do...

Comment: @ircmaxell A little more similar than `new $class` would be variable class params:  `return $this->$value`.  Not a method, mind you, but a parameter.  This is a variable variable of sorts, but still not technically `$$`.

Comment: @ircmaxell - that's a bit like saying arrays are not needed. why use $mydata["price"] and my $data["name"] when we can use $mydata_price and $mydata_name, or (another example) why use $filename[1] and $filename[2], when $filename_1 and $filename_2 works just as easily. in other words, indirection is one of the most basic principles in a programming language. it gives you the ability to do something with a value with caring what that value is for.