# stored procedure postgres and php

Tags: php, postgresql, stored-procedures

I am currently having trouble in regards of my stored procedure.

I have this stored procedure, under the schema **main**:
`register(LOGIN_ID varchar, PASSWORD varchar)`
I am trying to call this in a query but I got no luck,

```
$query = "SELECT main.register('test','pass123')";
$run = $pg_query($conn, $query);
```

This returns an error that ***No function matches the given name and argument types. You might need to add explicit type casts.*** 

Any insights please. Thanks.

Comment: i edited my post, sorry.

Comment: Does the function visible within the schema that you are connected ?

Comment: @LucM - I used navicat lite and yes it is visible in functions under the schema main.

Comment: Use pg_query_params() to avoid SQL injection

Comment: Why are you using `$pg_query` instead of `pg_query`...? It's a [function variable](http://php.net/functions.variable-functions) I think. You can check [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4891872/function-and-variable) too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try explicit cast:

```
$query = "SELECT main.register('test'::varchar,'pass123'::varchar)";
```

#### Edit:

Diagnose your problem with this query and report back the ouput.
*Find functions in all schemas in your database:*

```
SELECT n.nspname, p.proname, pg_catalog.pg_get_function_arguments(p.oid) as params
FROM   pg_catalog.pg_proc p
JOIN   pg_catalog.pg_namespace n ON n.oid = p.pronamespace
WHERE  p.proname ~~* '%my_function_name_here%'
AND    pg_catalog.pg_function_is_visible(p.oid);
```

Use the **same role** to connect!
Demo output:

```
 nspname |  proname | params
---------+----------+----------------------------------------
 public  | register | string text
 public  | register | login_id varchar, password varchar
 main    | register | string text, form text, maxlen integer
```

Here is Dee's output:

```
 nspname |  proname | params
---------+----------+----------------------------------------
 (0 rows)
```

Obviously, your role cannot see any functions of the name `register` with any parameters in any schema. Try the same as superuser - `postgres` in most cases.

- If you still see nothing, the function is just not there. You need to create it or you have a typo somewhere.
- If you see it as superuser, then the role you are connecting with lacks the necessary privileges, most likely on the schema `main`. In this case, the cure would be (as superuser or owner of schema `main`):

  ```
  GRANT USAGE ON SCHEMA main TO my_role;
  ```