# what is a variable with two $ sign ? $$ myVar

Tags: php, variables

I've seen $$var in a php test for a job interview. I was wondering what was it ..

Thanks

Comment: It's a variable variable: http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.variables.variable.php

Comment: [Manual](http://de3.php.net/manual/en/language.variables.variable.php), [Duplicate 1](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2715654/what-does-mean-in-php), [Duplicate 2](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4169882/what-is-in-php), [Duplicate 3](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4891872/function-and-variable)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$var = 'something';
$$var = 'lol';

echo $something will output "lol"
```

it's a variable variable.

Answer (score 1):

Variable variables - check the link out!

[Variable variables](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.variable.php)

Answer (score 0):

This will refer to the value of particular variable.

Eg :

```
$test = "Hi";

$var  = "test";
```

Now `$$var` will display **"Hi"**